# Page not redirecting correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I have set a redirect to happen and it isn't working here is the code:

```
if($result){

$sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `application` ORDER BY  `application`.`app_id`   
DESC LIMIT 0, 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result); 
echo $row['app_id'];
echo $app_id;
header('Location: payment.php?id=$row['app_id']');
exit();
}
```

The page isn't redirecting it is just returning a blank page. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: You would have seen the error, if you had used an IDE or editor with syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing last lines with

```
header('Location: payment.php?id='.$row['app_id']);
exit();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like

```
header('Location: payment.php?id='.$row['app_id']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this :

```
header("Location: payment.php?id=".$row['app_id']);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    if($result){

    $sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `application` ORDER BY  `application`.`app_id`   
    DESC LIMIT 0, 1");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result); 
    echo $row['app_id'];
    echo $app_id;
   ?>
  <script> 
   window.location=payment.php?id=<?php echo $row['app_id'];?>
  </script>
   <?php
    exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Redirecting via JS? Are you serious?

Comment: what is the issue.it will work try.

Comment: Yeah, it will work only if JS is enabled and you are downloading unnecessary data, as you are have to load the HTML file first instead just redirecting from the server side. Please use Google for any further disadvantages on using JS to redirect a website…